# is a line of symmetry going through the center of an octagon parallel to the ground it is on?

Tags: polygons, symmetry

I came across this question recently, It wanted me to find angle EDG assuming the line crossing between the octagon/polygon is it's line of symmetry.

My answer was 25 degrees, but A few friends said it was 70, I used alternate angles (the line of symmetry and the base) to find the angle of line ED to the base then subtract the exterior angle from the result.

This produces a valid looking answer using a valid theory (I suppose) but my friends claim is that Angles BAF, BCD, CDE and EFA = 65 degrees because the internal angles of the polygon must be 540 degrees and they believe BAF, BCD, CDE and EFA are equal. Am I right to assume that the line of symmetry provided must be parallel to the base?

[image: Hand Made Replica of question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the line of symmetry is parallel to the base.

Since you have a line of symmetry, the edges through the line of symmetry must be unchanged by the reflection: the line of symmetry needs to be perpendicular to the vertical edges, hence horizontal, just like the base.

I agree with your answer of $25^\circ$ for $\angle EDG $.

Answer (score 2):

What is 65 degrees? Except that, your answer and all else you said above is correct.

Comment: what my friends claim is that Angles BAF, BCD, CDE and EFA = 65 degrees because the internal angles of the polygon must be 540 degrees and they believe BAF, BCD, CDE and EFA are equal

Comment: @RandomUser Those angles are all the same, but they're not $65^\circ$. The interior angles of a hexagon ($n = 6$) add up to $(n - 2)\cdot 180^\circ = 4\cdot 180^\circ = 720^\circ$, not $540^\circ$. This being the case, those angles are all $110^\circ$, not $65^\circ$. Instead of using a hexagon, they could use the fact that each quadrilateral's angles sum to $360^\circ$, so $\angle BAF$ must be half of $360^\circ - 140^\circ$.

Comment: Also those angles are more than 90 degrees by inspection assuming the drawing has a reasonable proportion and cannot be 65< 90 degrees.Then itself you should get the doubt about their contention.